# Moses machine translation - using Moses with Anymalign

Tags: moses, giza++

Does anyone know how to replace GIZA++ in Moses with Anymalign which is obtained from [here](https://anymalign.limsi.fr/)

In fact, there is 9 [steps](http://www.statmt.org/moses/?n=FactoredTraining.HomePage) to using Moses, I want to start the step 4 without passing the step 2 and 3, but it seems to be impossible not to use GIZA++. Anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 0):

In the moses [manual](http://www.statmt.org/moses/manual/manual.pdf)
on page 351 in the section **8.3 Reference: All Training Parameters** there is described parameter `--first-step` *-- first step in the training process (default 1)*, so you can use `train-model.perl ... --first-step 4` to start training from step 4